# Why does Wolfram provide different graphs for $x^2 = 4$, $x^2 - 4 = 0$?

Tags: conic-sections, wolfram-alpha

I have the next cuadratic equation

$x^2=4$

Now do a algebra operations for draw the equation

$x^2-4=4-4$

$x^2-4=0$

Now draw the two equation and are different; why?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%C2%B2%3D4

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%C2%B2-4%3D0

thanks

Comment: The first plot is $y=x^2$ and it shows the intersection with $y=4$. Second is $y=x^2-4$ and shows intersection with $y=0$. Indeed both are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In the first image it is plotting the equation of $y=x^2$ on top of the plot of the equation $y=4$ and finding their intersection.

In the second image it is simply plotting the equation of $y=x^2-4$ and finding where it intersects with the $x$-axis.

Note that both correctly give the two solutions of $x=2$ and $x=-2$.

Comment: But if the exercise say "draw x²=-4", its correct the second plot?

Comment: @eslop It shouldn't be phrased as "draw $x^2=-4$."  If it is, then I'm sorry for you.  A correct phrasing of a question that I would expect you to be able to do is "draw $y=x^2-4$ (*and find where it crosses the $x$-axis*)" or perhaps "using graphs of functions, find what values of $x$ satisfy $x^2=4$"

Comment: realy the question is determine the plane regions for $z²

Comment: realy the question is determine the plane regions for $z² +(x-yi)²>=8$